# Create a Due Date Not Including Weekends from a column given Specific SLA Days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a "DaysUntilDue" column that says when a document needs to be completed by. I need to calculate the "Due Date" Based on the "Days Due" using the "Logged Day" column and exclude both Saturday and Sunday.

All I have is the columns that I know I need to work from.  I have code from a Case When Statement that excluded Sat and Sun but not sure how to incorporate that into what I need to do.  I have all the columns I need and all linked the way they need to be.  Really struggling with how to make a statement that says to calculate a due date from when the document's "logTime" using the existing "DaysUntilDue", but exclude weekends

```
SELECT     
CategoryName, 
DocCategory,
DaysUntilDue, 
TranNbr, 
DueDate, 
LogTime
FROM Queue INNER JOIN WQMTransactions ON Queue.TranNbr = WQMTransactions.TranNbr INNER  JOIN 
 ServiceQ INNER JOIN CategoryList ON ServiceQn.TranID =      CategoryList.TranID 
 INNER JOIN Category ON CategoryList.CategoryID =     Category.CategoryID 
 ON Queue.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID AND Queue.TranID = ServiceQ.TranID
```

maybe from lack of sleep, But Conceptually I can't determine how to do what.

I'm assuming I need to use this Case Statement that I built for another qry doing something similar.

```
CASE WHEN Doc IN ( 'POS', 'Card' )
     THEN CAST(DATEADD(d, CASE DATEPART(dw, DateEntered)
                            WHEN 7 THEN 2
                            WHEN 1 THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                          END, DateEntered) + ( DATEPART(dw,
                                                      DATEADD(d,
                                                      CASE DATEPART(dw,
                                                      DateEntered)
                                                      WHEN 7 THEN 2
                                                      WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                                      ELSE 0
                                                      END, DateEntered))
                                                - 2 + 5 ) % 5
          + ( ( DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(d, CASE DATEPART(dw, DateEntered)
                                          WHEN 7 THEN 2
                                          WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                          ELSE 0
                                        END, DateEntered)) - 2 + 5 )
              / 5 ) * 7 - ( DATEPART(dw,
                                     DATEADD(d,
                                             CASE DATEPART(dw,
                                                      DateEntered)
                                               WHEN 7 THEN 2
                                               WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                               ELSE 0
                                             END, DateEntered)) - 2 ) AS DATE)
     ELSE CAST(DATEADD(d, CASE DATEPART(dw, DateEntered)
                            WHEN 7 THEN 2
                            WHEN 1 THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                          END, DateEntered) + ( DATEPART(dw,
                                                      DATEADD(d,
                                                      CASE DATEPART(dw,
                                                      DateEntered)
                                                      WHEN 7 THEN 2
                                                      WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                                      ELSE 0
                                                      END, DateEntered))
                                                - 2 + 10 ) % 5
          + ( ( DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(d, CASE DATEPART(dw, DateEntered)
                                          WHEN 7 THEN 2
                                          WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                          ELSE 0
                                        END, DateEntered)) - 2 + 10 )
              / 5 ) * 7 - ( DATEPART(dw,
                                     DATEADD(d,
                                             CASE DATEPART(dw,
                                                      DateEntered)
                                               WHEN 7 THEN 2
                                               WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                               ELSE 0
                                             END, DateEntered)) - 2 ) AS DATE)
END AS 'Required SLA Date'
```

Comment: [Create a calendar table. It makes this kind of thing ***so*** much easier](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to correct your query. Also calculated the DueDate. DueDate is null when DaysUntilDue = 0.

```
SELECT     
CategoryName, 
DocCategory,
DaysUntilDue, 
TranNbr, 
LogTime,
dateadd(day, a.n, LoggedDay) DueDate
FROM Queue 
INNER JOIN WQMTransactions ON Queue.TranNbr = WQMTransactions.TranNbr 
INNER JOIN ServiceQ ON Queue.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID AND Queue.TranID = ServiceQ.TranID
INNER JOIN CategoryList ON ServiceQn.TranID = CategoryList.TranID 
INNER JOIN Category ON CategoryList.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID 
cross apply
(
select coalesce(max(number)+1, 0) n
from(
select top (DaysUntilDue) number from 
master..spt_values
WHERE TYPE = 'P'
and datediff(day, -number-1, LoggedDay) % 7 not in (5,6)
order by number
) 
a) 
a
```